# Spring Boot cannot find image assets

Tags: angular, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat

Spring Boot application is packaged as a `fat jar` file. I am utilizing the embedded `Tomcat` instance of `Spring Boot`. I did not alter the default locations in `application.properties` for `spring.resources.static-locations`. The production build for the Angular application is added under `/static`. `server.servlet.context-path` is set as `app`. `server.port` is `8480`. `base href` for `index.html` is `.`

```
/static
- /assets
-- /images
---- logo.png
---- /flags
------ flag.png
-- /scss
- index.html
- *.js
- *.js.map
- *.ttf
- *.eot
- *.svc
- *.woff
- *.woff2
```

I can load the interface and the Angular application is properly sending REST requests but I cannot load any image resource. `/assets/scss` is properly recognized in Dev Tools but not `/assets/images`. Also added this `@Configuration` according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzRG3LaOJ6w) video.

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfigurator extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry
        .addResourceHandler("/assets/images/**")
        .setCachePeriod(0)
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/assets/images/");
      }
}
```

Requests for image resources are sent to `localhost:8480/assets/images/logo.png` when it should be `localhost:8480/app/assets/images/logo.png`

[I am using IntelliJ IDE. Here is the screenshot of my `resources`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B7Ps.png)

[ChromeDevTools log using production build application. Replaced `app` with `afs`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgZhl.png)

Comment: Can you post the `base_url` property existing in index.html in Angular application

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal there is no `base_url` defined in the `index.html` of the Angular application. Or do I need to define that property for this to work?

Comment: Are you running your angular application in a tomcat server, packaging as a war or a jar?

Comment: @DulanjayaTennekoon I am running the Angular application using the embedded Tomcat server in Spring Boot. The Spring application is packaged as a jar file.

Comment: What is the app URL? what is the name of the jar?

Comment: @DulanjayaTennekoon since app is still under dev, I use `ip:port/app` as the url. jar name is `app.jar`

Comment: while making a prod build try with this command `ng build --prod --deploy-url=app/`

Comment: @BhushanBabar I already tried to build the app using that command. I guess I'll ask the front-end guys to settle this first.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the **baseUrl of your index file** as follows.

If your Jar name is app.jar, then your baseUrl has to be

```
<base href="/app/">
```

Comment: Already set the `base href` property as `/app/` but still not loading the images. `ng build --base-href=/app/`

Comment: Have you changed it from index.html? Try to change it from index.html and check

Comment: The output `index.html` after `ng build` gave the same pattern as you recommended.

edit: will attach dev tools request

Comment: Have you tried any production build, ng build --base-href=/app/ --prod

Comment: Yes. I have tried to build the Angular app using that. Will ask help from the front-end guys for this.